# Firefox - I think there's a separate Service Worker instance for each tab - why?

Tags: javascript, firefox, service-worker

## Problem statement

I'm currently developing a web application that tries to use service workers to share data between different tabs.

In the process, I have noticed that Firefox and Chrome exhibit different behavior:

- In Chrome, there is a single service worker instance that controls all tabs/windows opened within its scope.
- In Firefox, there appears to be a separate service worker instance for each tab/window that is opened.

While narrowing the cause down, I've reduced the issue to the minimal example seen below. Opening this test page twice each in both Firefox and Chrome (and reloading to let the worker take control), I find that while Chrome counts button clicks across *both* tabs, Firefox appears to keep a separate count for each tab. Why is this the case?

---

## Minimal example

#### test.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script src="test-client.js"></script>
        <input type="button" id="test-button" value="Click me!" />
        <div id="test-output">Click the button!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### test-client.js

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/test-worker.js');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
{
    let output = document.getElementById('test-output');
    document.getElementById('test-button').addEventListener('click', () =>
    {
        fetch('/worker/count').then((r) => r.text()).then((t) => { output.innerText = t; });
    });
});
```

#### test-worker.js

```js
let count = 0;
self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) =>
{
    if ((new URL(e.request.url).pathname) === '/worker/count')
    {
        ++count;
        e.respondWith(new Response(''+count));
    }
    else
        e.respondWith(fetch(e.request));
});
```

Comment: Have you figured this out?